# hover and old/new browser

Tags: hover

I made a rollover effect with a sprite-like technique

```
<a href="#">
<img width="240" height="160" src="240x160.jpg" class="…wp-post-image" alt="287" title="287" />
</a>


a{
  display:block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:120px;
  height: 160px;
}

a:hover img{
  margin-left: -120px;
}
```

it's work but is it better like this (in xhtml 1 stric or html5) ?

```
 a img:hover{
    margin-left: -120px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the background-image property instead of an actual image to avoid browser issues.

```
a{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:120px;
    height:160px;
    background:url(240x160.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
}
a:hover{
    background-position:-120px 0;
}
```

Comment: Agree with you, but it's in a CMS and had inline style is not great. I don't want a ie6 support (this is an effect).